# Filter rows by jsonb key mask

Tags: postgresql, json

**1. I have table UserData with following schema:**

- ID - bigint
- UserID - bigint
- Data - jsonb

**2. Data column jsonb has following structure:**

- date - contain timestamp
- text - contain description
- photo_* - contains photo's link (sometimes absent in json)

**3. Key photo_***:**

In photo_* key of jsonb Data field there are could be different values instead of asteriks (*), e.g.: photo_640, photo_1024, photo_1600

**4. What do I need**

I need to filter out only those rows in table UserData, that have any photo_* in jsonb Data column, i.e. Data field should contain key that starts with `photo_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hard time understanding how exactly your JSON values looks like, but I think you want something like this:

```
select ud.*
from userdata ud
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_object_keys(ud.data) as t(ky)
              where t.ky like 'photo%');
```